# "Let us know of any" or "Let us know if you have any"?

Tags: word-choice

When do I use 'of any' and 'if you have any'?

A specific example would be:

Please let us know **of any/if you have any** allergy or dietary requirements.

Comment: If the context makes it clear that you are speaking of requirements that the addressee has, _of any_ can be used. But if that's not obvious, one would prefer the more complete form, to improve clarity.

Comment: The two phrases mean different things. Both are fine—depending on what you're trying to ask.

Comment: In that context they're interchangeable.  But "Let us know of any available glibnexes" would be different from "Let us know if you have any available glibnexes", since the first case is asking if you know of any available from other sources as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, "let me know if you have any" means that you are asking someone if specifically they, or the business they are part of, have something specific.

> Please let me know when you have any more of those fresh croissants I like.

"Let me know of any" is more general, such as if someone else might also have the same or something similar.

> Can you tell me of anyone else that might have this widget?

For your example of dietary requirements, "if you have any" is specific to the person you are asking, whereas "of any" is directed more at a group.

"Please let us know if you have any allergy or dietary requirements."  This would be something you ask a person if specifically they have any issues with food.  You can still ask this of a group, but you wouldn't expect an answer of "I don't, but Karen is allergic to eggs."  Someone might still provide that answer, but it's not what you're asking.

"Please let us know of any allergy or dietary requirements."  This is something you might ask one person about other people.  When setting up a business meeting that includes food, you might ask this of a company rep, expecting an answer similar to "I don't think anyone is allergic to anything, but Gary is vegan, Jon is diabetic, and Sarah is Jewish." (Religion is used here only as another example of a specific set of dietary requirements.)

To make this more difficult, you can also ask an individual "please let us know of any allergy or dietary requirement you have".  That would be the same as asking "please let us know if you have any allergy or dietary requirements."

Unfortunately, there isn't a real good rule for this, since English almost always allows you to make a broad statement narrower by adding more words specifying what you're looking for.